# Are "smith" and "blacksmith" synonymous?

Tags: meaning

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/smith?s=t) says

> **noun**
>   1. a worker in metal.
>   2. a blacksmith.

Does this mean that they are the same?

Comment: You have the dictionary open, you can look at blacksmith too.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the close vote. Dictionary in hand, I still had this doubt and came here to ask this same question. The answer is apparently not really obvious (though it's not rocket-science either, sure).

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily. A smith could be a *[whitesmith](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whitesmith)*, a *[goldsmith](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/goldsmith)*, a *[silversmith](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/silversmith)*, or more figuratively in coinages such as *wordsmith* or *codesmith*.

A *blacksmith* is what would usually be meant, though.

Comment: I disagree your *"not necessarily"*. Rarely (archaically, imho) *gold-smith*, *silver-smith* may be hyphenated, but I can imagine no valid context where the word *smith* in isolation means anything other than a *blacksmith*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I can imagine the context where, for example, gold is under discussion and therefore _smith_ would be taken to mean _goldsmith_ but in most contexts it would be taken to mean _blacksmith_.

Comment: If I walk into a goldsmith's shop and ask "is the smith available?" I don't think they'd tell me I need to go to the blacksmith's place down the street.  (Unless the goldsmith was visiting the blacksmith, I suppose....)

Comment: You have a better imagination than me. I'd still ask to see the goldsmith.

Comment: Don't forget The Poopsmith

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Words are rarely used in true isolation.  While I would agree that *smith* without **any** context would generally imply blacksmith, the implied context (such as in a goldsmith's shop, as mentioned) could give easily *smith* meaning outside of blacksmith.

Answer (score 1):

In response to FumbleFingers (Don't have enough points to reply), a valid context for smith on its own:

> Shakespeare was a master of words, a veritable smith.

Comment: This is the concept that linguists call being "unmarked". We experience it when we notice how odd the phrases "acoustic guitar" or "paper book" sound when we think about them; they are no longer the unmarked case, any more than "brick-and-mortar store" is. With _smith_ one can, as with any word, create a context in which it would be unmarked. But one has to expend a lot of ingenuity to create all the presuppositions; better to write a novel.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but I think you're assuming unwarranted connotations of "expert craftsman" for the word. Granted, as [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=smith) points out, the direvation is *O.E. smið "one who works in metal" (jewelers as well as blacksmiths), from P.Gmc. *smithaz "**skilled worker**"*. But I've never come across anything like your example, and Google books has nothing relevant for *veritable smith, true smith, truly a smith* (I can't think of anything else to search for).

Comment: I don't disagree that my example is rare, it was more to point out that _smith_ by itself could allude to something else besides blacksmith. Even without my example, you say it could refer to any number of smithing professions, so the answer to @Mujeeb is "No, not always."